# Intellij IDEA hide empty middle folders

Tags: intellij-idea, project, directory

In the project view in Intellij IDEA, there is an option to "hide empty middle packages". 
Is there an equivalent for folders? I don't want a sole "src/main/java" to take up 3 lines...

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.

But if your folders are getting so long, you can always scroll the project pane to the right :)

It's also possible to use a different view (e.g. `Packages`) or define bookmarks and favourites to navigate around quickly, plus enable Auto-scroll from source.